# Form tag in .Net doesn't work if alone

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have just create a blank .net web form page and added a simple html form, it reads:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <form method="post" action="2ndpage.aspx">
            <input type="text" name="Value" />
            <input type="submit" value="click" />
        </form>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

If I click the button I'm not taken to 2ndpage.aspx. But If I add "`<form></form>`" just after the `<div>` so that the body now reads:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <form></form>
        <form method="post" action="2ndpage.aspx">
            <input type="text" name="Value" />
            <input type="submit" value="click" />
        </form>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

it works and I'm taken to 2ndpage.aspx when click.

I can look at this for another month but I'm sure I couldn't see where the bug is, I'd need a pair of fresh eyes. 
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You can't have multiple form tags nested within each other so I am surprised that it works at all, let alone adding ANOTHER form tag to the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good article here - https://web.archive.org/web/20170420110433/http://anderwald.info/internet/nesting-form-tags-in-xhtml/

It discusses not being able to nest one form in another form and also deals specifically with the scenario you describe.

Comment: I knwe it was something stupid but I needed a pair of fresh eyes to see it. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

you cant place form inside another form!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have nested form tags.

I'm not quite sure why it works when you add another empty form tag. But my guess is that the parser simply ignores the start of the tag and sees the end tag as the end tag for the first form. And therefore doesn't see it as nested forms anymore.